# Why can't I use this inside function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

Code:

```
const f: any = function(...args: any[]) {
    const a = this;
};
```

Error:

```
semantic error TS2683 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @ritaj the this is not in an arrow function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `noImplicitThis` compiler option enabled, and in new `f` function `this`  expression implicitly has the type `any` - hence the error.

To fix it - just specify the type explicitly using ["fake" `this` parameter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#specifying-the-type-of-this-for-functions):

```
const f: any = function(this: typeof target, ...args: any[]) {
    // ...
};
```

> By default the type of this inside a function is any. Starting with TypeScript 2.0, you can provide an explicit this parameter. this parameters are fake parameters that come first in the parameter list of a function